# Program not producing correct value - C++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to make a GPA calculator as practice. The program compiles but when it couts the avg, it returns a value such as -5.16205e+300. However, after calculating the avg in each for loop, if I put cout << avg; it returns the correct value in the end. I would appreciate any help, thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    {
        string ordinal, l_grade;
        int units;
        double num, sum, avg;

        cout << "How many units (maximum of 5)?: ";
        cin >> units;

        switch(units){
        case 0:
        {
            cout << "Can't calculate GPA with 0 units.";
        } break;

        case 1:
        {
            for(int i = 1; i <= units; i++){
                {
                    switch(i){
                        case 1:
                        ordinal = "first";
                        break;
                    }
                    cout << "Enter your " << ordinal << " letter grade: ";
                    cin >> l_grade;

                    if (l_grade == "A" || l_grade == "a"){
                        num = 4.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "A-" || l_grade == "a-"){
                        num = 3.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B+" || l_grade == "b+"){
                        num = 3.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B" || l_grade == "b"){
                        num = 3.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B-" || l_grade == "b-"){
                        num = 2.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C+" || l_grade == "c+"){
                        num = 2.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C" || l_grade == "c"){
                        num = 2.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C-" || l_grade == "c-"){
                        num = 1.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "D+" || l_grade == "d+"){
                        num = 1.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "D" || l_grade == "d"){
                        num = 1.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "F" || l_grade == "f"){
                        num = 0.00;
                    } else cout << "You entered an invalid letter grade.";
                }
                sum += num;
                avg = sum / units;
            }
            cout << "Your average is " << avg;
        } break;

        case 2:
        {
            for(int i = 1; i <= units; i++){
                {
                    switch(i){
                        case 1:
                        ordinal = "first";
                        break;

                        case 2:
                        ordinal = "second";
                        break;
                    }
                    cout << "Enter your " << ordinal << " letter grade: ";
                    cin >> l_grade;

                    if (l_grade == "A" || l_grade == "a"){
                        num = 4.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "A-" || l_grade == "a-"){
                        num = 3.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B+" || l_grade == "b+"){
                        num = 3.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B" || l_grade == "b"){
                        num = 3.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B-" || l_grade == "b-"){
                        num = 2.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C+" || l_grade == "c+"){
                        num = 2.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C" || l_grade == "c"){
                        num = 2.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C-" || l_grade == "c-"){
                        num = 1.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "D+" || l_grade == "d+"){
                        num = 1.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "D" || l_grade == "d"){
                        num = 1.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "F" || l_grade == "f"){
                        num = 0.00;
                    } else cout << "You entered an invalid letter grade.";

                }
                sum += num;
                avg = sum / units;
            }
            cout << "Your average is " << avg;
        } break;

        case 3:
        {
            for(int i = 1; i <= units; i++){
                {
                    switch(i){
                        case 1:
                        ordinal = "first";
                        break;

                        case 2:
                        ordinal = "second";
                        break;

                        case 3:
                        ordinal = "third";
                        break;
                    }
                    cout << "Enter your " << ordinal << " letter grade: ";
                    cin >> l_grade;

                    if (l_grade == "A" || l_grade == "a"){
                        num = 4.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "A-" || l_grade == "a-"){
                        num = 3.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B+" || l_grade == "b+"){
                        num = 3.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B" || l_grade == "b"){
                        num = 3.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B-" || l_grade == "b-"){
                        num = 2.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C+" || l_grade == "c+"){
                        num = 2.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C" || l_grade == "c"){
                        num = 2.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C-" || l_grade == "c-"){
                        num = 1.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "D+" || l_grade == "d+"){
                        num = 1.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "D" || l_grade == "d"){
                        num = 1.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "F" || l_grade == "f"){
                        num = 0.00;
                    } else cout << "You entered an invalid letter grade.";
                }
                sum += num;
                avg = sum / units;
            }
            cout << "Your average is " << avg;
        } break;

        case 4:
        {
            for(int i = 1; i <= units; i++){
                {
                    switch(i){
                        case 1:
                        ordinal = "first";
                        break;

                        case 2:
                        ordinal = "second";
                        break;

                        case 3:
                        ordinal = "third";
                        break;

                        case 4:
                        ordinal = "fourth";
                        break;
                    }
                    cout << "Enter your " << ordinal << " letter grade: ";
                    cin >> l_grade;

                    if (l_grade == "A" || l_grade == "a"){
                        num = 4.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "A-" || l_grade == "a-"){
                        num = 3.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B+" || l_grade == "b+"){
                        num = 3.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B" || l_grade == "b"){
                        num = 3.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B-" || l_grade == "b-"){
                        num = 2.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C+" || l_grade == "c+"){
                        num = 2.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C" || l_grade == "c"){
                        num = 2.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C-" || l_grade == "c-"){
                        num = 1.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "D+" || l_grade == "d+"){
                        num = 1.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "D" || l_grade == "d"){
                        num = 1.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "F" || l_grade == "f"){
                        num = 0.00;
                    } else cout << "You entered an invalid letter grade.";
                }
                sum += num;
                avg = sum / units;
            }
            cout << "Your average is " << avg;
        } break;

        case 5:
        {
            for(int i = 1; i <= units; i++){
                {
                    switch(i){
                        case 1:
                        ordinal = "first";
                        break;

                        case 2:
                        ordinal = "second";
                        break;

                        case 3:
                        ordinal = "third";
                        break;

                        case 4:
                        ordinal = "fourth";
                        break;

                        case 5:
                        ordinal = "fifth";
                        break;
                    }
                    cout << "Enter your " << ordinal << " letter grade: ";
                    cin >> l_grade;

                    if (l_grade == "A" || l_grade == "a"){
                        num = 4.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "A-" || l_grade == "a-"){
                        num = 3.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B+" || l_grade == "b+"){
                        num = 3.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B" || l_grade == "b"){
                        num = 3.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "B-" || l_grade == "b-"){
                        num = 2.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C+" || l_grade == "c+"){
                        num = 2.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C" || l_grade == "c"){
                        num = 2.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "C-" || l_grade == "c-"){
                        num = 1.67;
                    } else if(l_grade == "D+" || l_grade == "d+"){
                        num = 1.33;
                    } else if(l_grade == "D" || l_grade == "d"){
                        num = 1.00;
                    } else if(l_grade == "F" || l_grade == "f"){
                        num = 0.00;
                    } else cout << "You entered an invalid letter grade.";
                }
                sum += num;
                avg = sum / units;
            }
            cout << "Your average is " << avg;
        } break;

        default:
        {
            cout < "You entered an invalid number.";
        } break;
    }
}
return  0;
```

}

Comment: `-5.16205e+300` maybe you forgot to initialize one or more variables like these: `double num, sum, avg;`. Note that local variables are not automatically set to 0. They will have an indeterminate value considered as random garbage.

Comment: @drescherjm That did it! Thank you so much! Is there a reason why it doesn't take over the value from cin?

Comment: `sum += num;` with `sum` starting out as a random garbage number what is sum + num?